# MongoDB $in and $ne

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I'd like to fetch some Documents where a field can possibly be `$in` some array (conditional query if a filter was set).

However, I need to also unconditionally check whether this same field is `$ne: null`. I understand the `$in: [some values]` can be used to prevent null from being retrieved, but the problem is that part of the query is conditional based on if a filter is set.

Is there a more efficient way of doing what's below? Will that even work?

```
db.Parents.fetch({
    childId: { $in: childIds },
    childId: { $ne: null }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [$and](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/and/) operator

```
db.Parents.fetch({
    $and:[
      {childId: { $in: childIds }},
      {childId: { $ne: null }}
    ]
});
```

Comment: This is what I was thinking of doing. But https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/and/ it seems like it's more of a logical AND. Documentation says it would short-circuit. So wouldn't that mean if the first clause failed that it wouldn't even check the second? I have to unconditionally make sure that the $ne:null one gets evaluated

Comment: @user2402616 Yes, but for positive meaning. If filtering childId is -1 (for instance), first clause will return false and document is filtered. BTW: you can swap clauses, setup null check as 1st clause and you make sure nulld never pass